# Open GL ES - what is the best way to draw multiple objects

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am using Open GL ES 2.0 in iOS (using GLkit) and wonder what would be the best way to draw multiple objects, say polylines:

1. Use a separate vertex buffer for each polyline, without an index buffer, and simply draw GL_LINE_LOOP. In this case there would be a draw call for each object.
2. Gather all the vertices into one buffer and prepare an index buffer. In this case there would be one draw call which will draw GL_LINES.
3. Any other way to do this.

Also, how would the answer change if each line has a different color (but the color does not change for each vertex).

Comment: There is a huge difference, between saying the "correct way" and "the best way"

Comment: Correct and best sounds the same to me :). Lets call is the best way in terms of performance

Comment: If yours objects has more then ~100 vertices use VAO and indices.

Comment: Correct != Best... The correct way is not always the best way, and the best way is not always the correct way... Bottom line, there is no correct way, though the best way would be to use buffers (VAOs and VBOs) you can also do instanced rendering.

Comment: And if they have less than 100 vertices (say around 20-30)

Comment: *"how would the answer change if each line has a different color"* - In this case you wouldn't need an index buffer in your second solution, as it would be plain useless.

Comment: @Vallentin The question if to use VAOs and VBOs is completely orthogonal to the question how to structure the primitives and draw calls as asked here.

Comment: @ChristianRau why i would not need an index buffer? why would it be useless?

Comment: @ErikSapir Because when each line has a different color instead of each vertex, you will need two different vertices for each geometric vertex anyway, one with the color of the starting line and one with the color of the ending line. So the benefit of an index buffer (which is reusing of vertices) would vanish, as you would need 2n vertices for n lines anyway and there isn't any vertex reuse.

Comment: @ChristianRau yes, i see what you mean. This is correct. Is it anyway a real issue to have many draw operations? I really can't figure it out from the various tutorials i read. Some say that you must lower number of draw calls to the minimum possible, why others say that all modern mobile devices can handle hundreds of draw calls without any problem.

Comment: draw object one by one, arrange the object from nearest to farthest. then use culling and depth test to mnimize draw calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're defining “best” in terms of performance:

It should always be faster to use a single vertex buffer, as long as all your polylines have the same vertex attributes and it’s straightforward to gather them into a single vertex buffer (i.e. you don’t frequently need to gather and repack them). This requires fewer OpenGL ES API calls to rebind the data, since you can use a single call to `glVertexAttribPointer*` per attribute and rely on the `first` argument to `glDrawArrays` or offset indices (as you described in your question).

Assuming each polyline has distinct vertices and vertex counts, instancing doesn’t apply. I think at this point there are probably two good options here, along a space-for-CPU-time tradeoff curve:

1. Pass your polyline color as a vertex attribute, but by setting the current value via `glVertexAttrib4f`, rather than using actual per-vertex array data. Loop through your polylines, updating the color with `glVertexAttrib4f`, then using `glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, first, count)`, where `first` and `count` are defined by how you packed your polylines into the single vertex buffer.
2. Pass your polyline color as a vertex attribute, and expand the set of data you store per vertex to include the color, which is repeated for every vertex in a polyline. (This is where instancing would have helped you if you were repeating the same polyline.) Prepare the index buffer, much like you were doing for 2) in your question.

Note that this proposed 1) is similar to the 1) in your question, but all vertex data lives in a single vertex buffer anyway. Since both solutions now use a single vertex buffer, the choice is primarily between whether you are willing to make additional calls to `glVertexAttrib4f` and `glDrawArrays` in order to avoid allocating extra memory for repeated colors and index data. Note that changing a vertex attribute’s current value and the `start` offset used for each draw should still be significantly cheaper than binding new vertex buffers and resetting vertex array state.